# Save dataframe as pickle without over-writing

Tags: pandas, append, pickle

I was looking for a way to append to a pickle file (created from `DataFrame.to_pickle()` function) and do not want to overwrite it.

I have a csv file at a URL that changes every day and that csv does not have a datetime stamp. I am pulling that csv file and putting it into a dataframe. In that process, I create a date column since the csv does not have a datetime stamp.

Issue: The problem I am running into is that I don't know how to append to the dataframe to the next day.

My solution was to save the dataframe to a pickle file with today's date. Then tomorrow I download the csv and append to the same pickle file but then ran into the issue of how to accomplish it.

Alternatively, I suppose I write/append to csv but before I go down that path, I thought of asking for doing the same with pickle file.

Comment: These are probably your options, from simplest to most complicated: (1) hold a dataframe in memory and append the new rows to it; (2) append the new rows to a csv file that already exists on disk; (3) read a data frame into memory from a pickle file, then append the new rows to it; (4) append the new rows to a pickled dataframe on disk, without reading it into memory (may not even be possible). Is there a reason you chose option (4) over the others?

Comment: Thanks Matthias for the clarity. I was thinking of option 3 not 4. Now I am going to try that.